# Recurring Order Modeling with Django

Tags: django, django-models

What would be better Logic approach to setup recurring Order modelling.

There is Order model with tons of Order information along with

```
    o.recurrence_unit
    o.recurrence_period
```

These ones are already calculated:

```
    o.expire (date )
    o.days_left (number, 31)
```

How would you setup parent / child relationship.

The idea I was scratching with "related" field back to original Order model. There is a possibility, the child recurring orders would need an model to themselves. Email reminders need to be sent to.

Comment: This is too vague and generalistic to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree-node-like models could be represented database-wise with a "parent" field pointing to the same model.

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')
```

However, caution is advised when you have to travel the "tree", as you should load from databse all instances and then travel it in Python using some sort of data structure rather than accessing your database multiple times with the antipattern `some_instance.parent.parent.parent`.